# How to check whether a Groovy class overrides a parent's method

Tags: groovy, introspection

I have two Groovy classes, `Child1` and `Child2`, which derive from an abstract parent class `Parent`. The parent class implements three methods, only different in their parameters (i.e. their method names are the same).

Now I have an instance of the child class. The task is to check whether that object's class implements (overrides) one or more of the parent's methods.

I tried with Groovy's `Inspector` on the child class object. This gives me a list of all methods, but I am not sure how to read the output. In particular I do not understand whether the method I am looking for is implement in the child class, or only in the parent class.

Can anybody help me with this, do I maybe need another way of introspection?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So I ended up with this solution, which does exactly what I wanted:

```
def pattern = ~/^public void ... $/
for(method in obj.metaClass.methods.findAll { it ==~ pattern })
{
    /* Do some stuff... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. I still feel there is a groovier way. Try using `collectInheritedMethods()` to see if you get what you wanted. I deliberately wanted to return a list of matched methods instead of just a flag because you can also see the methods that are implemented from super class, Groovy truth (`if(collectInheritedMethods(..))`) on the list will be sufficient for flagging.

```
abstract class Parent {
    void method1() { println "No Param" }
    void method1( def a ) { println "param: $a" }
    void method1( List a, Map b ) { println "param: $a and $b" }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    void method1() { println "A: no param" }
    void method1( def a ) { println "A: param $a" }
    void method1( def a, def b ) { println "A: param $a and $b" }
}

List collectInheritedMethods( Class parent, Class child ) {
    List inheritedMethods = [] 
    def parentMethods = parent.declaredMethods.findAll { !it.synthetic }
    def childMethods = child.declaredMethods.findAll { !it.synthetic }

    for( chMet in childMethods ) {
        for( paMet in parentMethods ) {
            if( chMet.name == paMet.name && 
                  chMet.parameterTypes == paMet.parameterTypes && 
                     chMet.returnType == paMet.returnType ) {

                inheritedMethods << child.getMethod( chMet.name, 
                                                    chMet.parameterTypes )
                                         .toGenericString()

                //if only a flag is required to check if method implemented
                //flag = true
                //break
            }
        }
    }

    //Groovier way
    /*inheritedMethods = childMethods.findAll { chMet -> 
        parentMethods.findAll { paMet -> 
            chMet.name == paMet.name && 
                chMet.parameterTypes == paMet.parameterTypes && 
                    chMet.returnType == paMet.returnType 
        } 
    }*/

    inheritedMethods
}

assert collectInheritedMethods( Parent, Child ) == 
       ["public void Child.method1()", 
        "public void Child.method1(java.lang.Object)"]
```